# iPod 2G not allowing sync of supported video

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch, encoding

I have some videos that I would like to copy onto an old iPod Touch 2Gen for my daughter, so that she doesn't have to see the horror of YouTube.  The specs for the device ([as taken from here](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP496?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)) show that the following are supported video types:

> H.264 video, up to 1.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Low-Complexity version of the H.264 Baseline Profile with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats; H.264 video, up to 2.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Baseline Profile up to Level 3.0 with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats; MPEG-4 video, up to 2.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Simple Profile with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats

Quicktime shows the following when playing the video:
[image]

And iTunes has the following in *Get Info*:
[image]

But when I try to copy the file via iTunes, it says the file is not supported:
[image]

How can I found out exactly what is is complaining about, so I can fix it?

Comment: Nothing is coming to mind, but Quicktime will gladly re-encode it for iPod touch so you can get your sync on while we scratch our heads on why a file that looks fine won't sync. http://cl.ly/T5xV

Comment: Tried exporting from Quicktime to iPod Touch/iPhone 3G (the lowest setting it offered) and get the same results.  This happens for all the files, which are actually direct pulls from youtube containers.

Comment: I am not sure what video apps still support the 2nd Generation iPod Touch, but if you can get something like GoodReader to work, then you can transfer the videos into that. Most of them will play a wider range of video types than the Movies app in iOS.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen people mention that when they had an issue like this they changed the resolution to 640 by 480 pixels.

Comment: That was going to be my guess. Try resizing the video and see if that helps.

Comment: Only thing I can add is to open the file in Quicktime 7. That version usually offers more Apple-related information about the video than other apps (I think except Handbrake). This must be a special video for your daughter. I hope you get a good solution. Oh one other idea - it may be iTunes that is causing the fuss. Is there another way to load videos than through iTunes.. In that regard, are there other videos you could try to load..

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running one of the files through [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/). I know there is an option in the devices presets that is called iPod. Perhaps that has the right settings. If that works, you can look at the differences between the Handbrake settings and what Quicktime has and perhaps pick up something that way.

Using the iPod presets in Handbrake will select the 'iPod 5G support' and add the MOOV atom to the video file. The MOOV atom is the index information in MPEG-4 files, this atom makes it possible to play the file before it is completely loaded.

[image: Handbrake Default Presets]

Answer (score 0):

I was having issues using Handbrake for my iPod Touch 2nd Gen.  The trick was going to the Video tab and setting...

H.264 Profile: Baseline

H.264 Level:   3.0

I also set the max width to 720 on all my videos, but unsure how big the can be.